# How to get new textures without sacrificing the vanilla ones?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I saw a command block contraption adding a bunch of new blocks mechanics, etc.
I wonder, is it possible to add new textures without getting rid of the vanilla ones?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.

What you can't do is create new blocks with a custom texture without replacing a vanilla one.

What you can do however is creating block models using custom textures for specific ITEMS and display those with the help of ArmorStands holding them/wearing it on their head.
You can make them look like regular blocks and have an almost unlimited amount of them, since every damage value of every item can be used to make it look differently as well as depending on the Unbreaking tag you can double these amounts. So a single diamond hoe can hold over 2000 different models (which would cause a lot of lag though).

Comment: Sure, but what if I want to make a custom texture for a slab - in this case you can't use barriers and invisible armour stands.

And what about custom liquids?

Comment: you can make custom slabs (as long as you are able to occupy the block below) by using the custom textures explained above and an invisible noAI shulker riding the armorstand. Koder has a pretty good video about this here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5zow9d66N0
he uses fallingsand, but you should be able to extract what you need from that.

as far as custom liquids go: no, you can't create custom liquids. You may be able to get close, but not without a LOT of commands and textures.